# AWS CLI EC2 describe-address with IAM restriction

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam

I'm trying to find a way of listing/describing the public IP (doesn't have to be an EIP) of an EC2 instance. I've read about Describe* and I'm aware of the limitation of not being able to specify the resource in the policy.

So my question is:

While specifying the resource in the policy, is there any way for me to get the public IP of an EC2 instance? Is there any commands that can be used in awscli that would return the public IP while running under a user/group that would allow this action only within a specified resource?

I basically want to apply a policy that gives the user/group permission to get the IP only from a specified EC2 instance ID.

Thank you!

Comment: An ec2 instance can look up it's own public IP without any IAM permissions via instance metadata.

Comment: Care to add more info? How can you retrieve it, for example?

Comment: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful. Since I'm starting an EC2 instance from a script, I don't believe I can get to that page without querying the instance ID, though. 

Since I don't have an EIP on the instance and the IP changes every time it boots, even though interesting to know, I don't believe I can use it in a script (I didn't mention the script part in my question though). TY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only command that can get an EC2 instance's public IP address is the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --instance-ids i-abcdef
```

Unfortunately, there is no IAM policy syntax capable of restricting the command to only a single EC2 instance. `describe-instances` does not allow resource-level permissions. So to give access to this command requires giving access for all EC2 instances.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm accepting this as the answer, but I'm still surprised that no one in AWS thought about the need to get an IP from an instance without allowing to get an IP from ALL instances. 

Is my case so "extreme" or out of the ordinary? Weird. Nevertheless, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the Public IP

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-the-instance-id-here | grep PublicIpAddress | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed 's/[",]//g'
```

And you can grant your AWS CLI user `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` access.

Comment: Should that be describe-instanceS? Also, I can't find the AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly action. My policy currently allows for ec2:DescribeInstances and ec2:StopInstances and ec2:StartInstances, both limited to the resource of the instance ID. 

However, as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html#iam-example-instances, I can't define a resource with describe-instances:

"The * wildcard is also necessary in cases where the API action does not support resource-level permissions."

Or am I reading it wrong? 

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is describe-instances. My mistake on the syntax. I've corrected it. Hope this link helps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html

Comment: Under "My Security Credentials", you can update the permission of the User.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my point. I'm using an IAM policy, and describe-instances doesn't allow resource level limiting.